# jQuery calendar custom view

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Has anyone ever seen a jQuery plugin which supports a type of view like this:

```
        |   User 1  |      User 2    |
10:00   |   Event 1 |                |
10:30   |           |                |  
11:00   |   Event 2 |                |
11:30   |           |                |
12:00   |   Event 3 |     Event 3    |
```

Those plugins (links below) are very nice, and i'm planning to go through the code and try to make a "custom view", it's kind of week view, but User instead of days.

wdCalendar (link removed)

[fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

any ideas?

== UPDATE:
I found a solution using fullcalendar plugin. -> http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490

Comment: What do you need a plugin for? If you're just planning on removing the dates from a calendar then what are you using the calendar for? It sounds like what you're looking to do is display tabular data. Maybe just use a table?

Comment: Given the plugins he's listing, I'm assuming that he still wants the navigation of a calendar in a "daily" view.

Comment: Exactly, it would be an event manager for multiple users. wdCalendar looks perfect for me, except for it is missing that feature. thanks guys...